# How to generate an id for a newly created model instance using django and DRF?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to figure out how to create instances of a model in my view.

I think the problem is in the view itself.

**views.py**

```
...
tag = Tag.objects.create(
            name='randomlycreatedtagfor test',
            language='de')
...
```

I keep getting this error:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "app_tagging_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(57949) already exists.
```

However, here is my code for the model and the serializer. Maybe this is where I am doing something wrong.

**models.py**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tag_data = validated_data.pop('tag')
        Tag.objects.create(**tag_data)
        return tag_data

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or ''
```

**serializers.py**

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = Tag
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'language')

  def create(self, validated_data):
    return Tag.objects.create(**validated_data)

  def to_representation(self, data):
    data = super().to_representation(data)
    return data
```

Is there a way to generate an id in a simpler way?

Comment: Why are you manually creating IDs? The database will automatically create IDs for you.

Comment: @xyres Because I am relatively new to django and I knew how to do it this way.

Comment: Unless there's a specific purpose to generating IDs manually, let the database take care of that.

Comment: I have found a way now by using BigAutoField but I am getting the same error. I have updated my code. I have also deleted the db and rebuilt it and made migrations and the error is still there.

Comment: I think your `id` field is the problem. No need to make a manual `id` field, django will automatically created `id` field by default.

Comment: @OmayerHasanMarif so you men I should just take it out entirely and leave my code as it is above then? and when I create an instance I simply don't set an id like above.

Answer (score 0):

Django by default provides an id field as a primary_key so you don't need to manually put it in the model, just delete the line, delete your migration files and your DB file, `makemigrations` => `migrate` then try it.

Comment: I have, the error is still there. Weirdly enough it's only there every couple of tries but it is still there.

Comment: and from your Tag serializer delete the id field

Comment: I've also done that. Maybe I'll reset the db again and see then.

Comment: `class CustomUserCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]
    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TagSerializer`
put this code in the view.py and configure a url for it and test trough the api